# Physics Modeling Software for Wave Interference

Tags: simulation, scientific-computing

I am an 11th grade student taking Differential Equations (which, for my class, is largely just hanging out with the teacher).  We came up with an interesting idea which we would hope to test with some advanced software.  Essentially we need software which:

1. Can simulate interference of sound waves bouncing off of various shapes, and propagating through various materials.
2. Is relatively easy to use (no compiling to install it, programming in Python or Java, no additional installations necessary (CUDA, etc), and (preferably), is hardware accelerated.

Any suggestions?  Free, free trial, or cheap student license would be preferred.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple free online simulations, although they don't let you view interactions with objects they do allow viewing interaction between sources and let you vary parameters of the sources.

https://www.edumedia-sciences.com/en/media/749-water-wave-interference

https://www.falstad.com/ripple/